# Flask: Url_for argument is passed as query parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I'm trying to pass a json object to url_for, but it's passed as a query parameter (appended to the URL) instead of being passed as an argument to the function, hence getting a 'Missing positional argument' error. Using Flask on Python 3.5.

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

My code:

```
##VIEWS.PY
@projects.route('/exportdata', methods=['GET','POST'])
def exportdata(export):
    return Response(export,
            mimetype='application/json',
            headers={'Content-Disposition': 'attachment;filename=export.json'})
```

---

```
<!-- HTML-->
<p> Download data <a href="{{ url_for('projects.exportdata', export=export) }}">here </a></p>
```

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to declare export as a parameter in your route.

```
import json

from flask import jsonify

##VIEWS.PY
@projects.route('/exportdata/<export>', methods=['GET','POST'])
def exportdata(export):
    return jsonify(**json.loads(export))
```

Comment: Thanks. When I try now I get a 'not found' error and the whole JSON content is still in the URL bar. I would like to view the json or download it.

Comment: Could you try the updated answer I just edited? Thanks.

Comment: Also, bear in my that passing the JSON to url_for() like that will always send the JSON as a query parameter, and it will always be visible in the URL.If you don't want that, I suggest either generating the JSON in the exportdata() route itself, or using HTTP's POST method. For that you would need an HTML <form> with a hidden input field, and replacing that <a> with an <input>.

Comment: The browser hangs when I try to click on the link. For the POST solution, what should it look like?  Where should I pass the JSON file? Thanks
<form action="{{url_for('projects.exportdata')}}" method="post"><input> here</input> </form>

Comment: What version of Flask are you running? I tried this using Flask 0.11 and its built-in web server, worked correctly. The contents of the JSON will have to be in an input of type="hidden". Here: <form action="{{url_for('projects.exportdata')}}" method="post"> <input type="hidden" name="export" value="{{export}}"> <input> here</input> </form>